# Como usar plural com String Resources?

Tags: android, string, internacionalização

Para a internacionalização, o Android usa *String Resources*. Como posso aproveitar esse recurso para usar o plural de modo a evitar "gambiarras" com múltiplos `if`'s?

Exemplo:

```html
<string name="friends_none">Você não tem amigos ainda</string>
<string name="friends_one">Você tem 1 amigo</string>
<string name="friends_plural">Você tem %1$d amigos</string>
```

```java
if (friends == 1) {
    text = getString(R.string.friends_one);
} else if (friends > 1) {
    text = getString(R.string.friends_plural, friends);
} else {
    text = getString(R.string.friends_none);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para esta situação específica, o framework do android fornece um recurso chamado de "Quantity Strings" (Strings de quantidade).

1. Crie um arquivo dentro do diretório `res/values` com um nome qualquer. Exemplo: `res/values/strings_plurais.xml`
2. Este arquivo precisa ter a tag raiz `resources`, e dentro dela você coloca a tag `plurals`.
3. Dentro da tag `plurals` coloque um atributo `name` para identificá-la. Exemplo: `name="respostas_corretas"`.
4. Para criar a string, crie uma tag `item`, e coloque um atributo `quantity`. Exemplo: `quantity="one"` (para singular) ou `quantity="other"` (para plural).
5. Depois, dentro da tag `item`, você coloca a string a ser utilizada no layout. Exemplo:
   `<item quantity="one">Pontuação: %d ponto.</item>`

O arquivo .XML final deve se parecer com isto:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <plurals name="respostas_corretas">
            <item quantity="one">Pontuação: %d ponto.</item>
            <item quantity="other">Pontuação: %d pontos.</item>
        </plurals>
    </resources>
```

Agora no código-fonte Java, a string pode ser obtida desta maneira:

```
    // Chamando numeroRespostasCorretas() para obter o número de respostas corretas
    int nRespostasCorretas = numeroRespostasCorretas();
    // Obtendo a referência de Resources
    Resources resources = getResources();
    // Chame o getQuantityString() e passe como paramêtros o ID do plurals criado e passe a variável a ser formatada duas vezes (uma para o formatador e outra para o framework determinar, baseada na variável, se é singular ou plural)
    String respostasCorretas = resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.respostas_corretas, nRespostasCorretas, nRespostasCorretas);
```

Em Kotlin da mesma forma:

```
  val nRespostasCorretas = numeroRespostasCorretas()
  val respostasCorretas = resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.respostas_corretas, 
  nRespostasCorretas , nRespostasCorretas)
```

Para mais informações sobre este tópico e sobre recursos de string no Android:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource?hl=pt-br#top_of_page